# DropDownListFor como usar?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com uma dúvida em como popular e depois pegar o item selecionado de um `DropDownListFor`, sendo que estou utilizando arquitetura DDD e Entity Framework.

No caso aqui minha classe `ServiceProviderViewModel` tem que ter relacionamento com outras classes. Gostaria de saber como fazer para popular esse *Helper* na *View* de `Create`.

Segue códigos:

```
public class ServiceProviderViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceProviderId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, informe o nome do colaborador.")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome:")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome da Mãe:")]
    public string MotherName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome do Pai:")]
    public string FatherName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail:")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, informe um formato de e-mail válido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nascimento:")]
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime DateRegister { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, informe o departamento para o colocaborador.")]
    [Display(Name = "Departamento:")]       
    public int DepartamentId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, informe o departamento para o colocaborador.")]
    [Display(Name = "Cargo/Função:")]
    public int PositionId { get; set; }

    public virtual DepartamentViewModel Departaments { get; set; }
    public virtual PositionViewModel Positions { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ServiceProviderAddressViewModel> ServiceProviderAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ServiceProviderPhoneViewModel> ServiceProviderPhone { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ServiceProviderInfoViewModel> ServiceProviderInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<InfoBankViewModel> InfoBank { get; set; }
}
```

No *Controller*:

```
 public class ServiceProviderController : Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceProviderAppService _serviceProviderApp;

    public ServiceProviderController(IServiceProviderAppService serviceProviderApp)
    {
        _serviceProviderApp = serviceProviderApp;
    }

    // GET: ServiceProvider
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var serviceProviderViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ServiceProvider>, IEnumerable<ServiceProviderViewModel>>(_serviceProviderApp.GetAll());
        return View(serviceProviderViewModel);
    }

    // GET: ServiceProvider/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: ServiceProvider/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ServiceProviderViewModel serviceProvider)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var serviceProviderDomain = Mapper.Map<ServiceProviderViewModel, ServiceProvider>(serviceProvider);
            _serviceProviderApp.Add(serviceProviderDomain);
            _serviceProviderApp.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(serviceProvider);
    }

...
```

Para cada classe que `ServiceProvider` se relaciona tenho os *models* específicos para realização do CRUD. Só não sei como devo fazer para funcionar essa mistura de *models* entre as *views* e *controllers*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@uitan, essa exception está mascarando o real problema que deve ser apenas validação do seu form.
Você deve carregar as ViewBags do ação post como fez na ação Get.
seu post deve ficar assim:

```
// POST: ServiceProvider/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ServiceProviderViewModel serviceProvider)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var serviceProviderDomain = Mapper.Map<ServiceProviderViewModel, ServiceProvider>(serviceProvider);
        _serviceProviderApp.Add(serviceProviderDomain);
        _serviceProviderApp.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //FALTAM ESSAS LINHAS:
    ViewBag.Position = new SelectList(_positionApp.GetAll(), "PositionId", "Description");
    ViewBag.Departament = new SelectList(_departamentApp.GetAll(), "DepartamentId", "Description");

    return View(serviceProvider);
}
```

Marque como resolvido se funcionar. :)

Comment: vlw. Funcionou!

Answer (score 3):

Código levando em consideração que o *PositionId* deveria ser uma combo:

**Na Action Get:**

**Obs:** Você deve passar a ViewBag.Position

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Position = new SelectList(_serviceProviderApp.SeuMetodoDeObterPositions(), "PositionId", "SeuCampoDescricao");

    return View();
}
```

**Na view:**

**Obs:** Esse Código coloca a primeira opção em branco e depois os dados vindo da ViewBag.

```
@Html.DropDownList("PositionId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Position, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Mas, como a classe Position é um outro model, devo fazer uma chamada do mesmo dentro do controller de ServiceProvider? A idéia não é exatamente criar controllers distintos para cada model?

Comment: @UitanMaciel, eu falei Position somente como ilustração. No lugar de Position coloque a model referente a sua combo.

Comment: Está funcionando bem. Está populando o DropDownListFor. No entanto está dando erro: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'DepartamentId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. Está com problema em converter o tipo.

Comment: Talvez eu precise ver seu código, mas entenda que o método ObterPositions (ou seja lá qual for o nome do seu método precisa retornar algo do tipo IEnumerable<Position>, com a classe Position tendo uma propriedade PositionId como chave e uma propriedade Descricao que devem ser iguais aos dois últimos  parâmetros passados para o New SelectList.

Comment: olha o código abaixo:

Comment: @UitanMaciel, olhei o código que você postou e me parece ok. Complicado saber exatamente qual é o problema agora. Provavelmente você deixou passar algum detalhe, tente debugar, veja em que linha ocorre o problema, veja a innerexception. Cheque a implementação da classe Departament e do repositório. Parece que o problema está ao fazer o Get e não o Post, já que no post você não usa ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

No Domain:

```
 public class ServiceProvider
{
    #region Attributs
    public int ServiceProviderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MotherName { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birth{ get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRegister { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Foreingkeys
    public int DepartamentId { get; set; }
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Properties Navigations
    public virtual Departament Departaments { get; set; }
    public virtual Position Positions { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

public class Position
{
    #region Attributs
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRegister { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Relationships Other Class
    public virtual IEnumerable<ServiceProvider> ServiceProviders { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

 public class Departament
{
    #region Attributs
    public int DepartamentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRegister { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Relationships Other Class
    public virtual IEnumerable<ServiceProvider> ServiceProviders { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Na ViewModel (Camada de Apresentação)

```
public class ServiceProviderController : Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceProviderAppService _serviceProviderApp;
    private readonly IPositionAppService _positionApp;
    private readonly IDepartamentAppService _departamentApp;

    public ServiceProviderController(IServiceProviderAppService serviceProviderApp, IPositionAppService positionApp, IDepartamentAppService departamentApp)
    {
        _serviceProviderApp = serviceProviderApp;
        _positionApp = positionApp;
        _departamentApp = departamentApp;
    }

    // GET: ServiceProvider
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var serviceProviderViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ServiceProvider>, IEnumerable<ServiceProviderViewModel>>(_serviceProviderApp.GetAll());
        return View(serviceProviderViewModel);
    }

    // GET: ServiceProvider/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: ServiceProvider/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Position = new SelectList(_positionApp.GetAll(), "PositionId", "Description");
        ViewBag.Departament = new SelectList(_departamentApp.GetAll(), "DepartamentId", "Description");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: ServiceProvider/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ServiceProviderViewModel serviceProvider)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var serviceProviderDomain = Mapper.Map<ServiceProviderViewModel, ServiceProvider>(serviceProvider);
            _serviceProviderApp.Add(serviceProviderDomain);
            _serviceProviderApp.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

Na View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartamentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartamentId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Departament, string.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartamentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PositionId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PositionId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Position, string.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PositionId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Os métodos GetAll() e os de CRUD são chamados por repositórios genéricos. O problema está exatamente quando tento submeter o formulário. Apresenta o erro que comentei anteriormente.

Comment: acabei de ajudar um amigo que teve esse problema, no caso dele a ViewModel estava inválida.
Coloque um breakpoint na linha:
`if (ModelState.IsValid)`
e veja que campo está com erro.

Comment: @ViniciusGrund extamente, o (ModelState.IsValid) não está válido. E o erro que apresenta é An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'DepartamentId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: @ViniciusGrund olha abaixo a img do Model